# In Fargate container why can I CRUD S3 but can't create a presigned post

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-fargate

I'm using node in a docker container and locally I use my IAM keys for both creating, reading and deleting files to an S3 bucket as well as creating pre-signed posts. When up on a Fargate container, I create a taskRole and attach a policy which gives it full access to S3.

```
    taskRole.attachInlinePolicy(
      new iam.Policy(this, `${clientPrefix}-task-policy`, {
        statements: [
          new iam.PolicyStatement({
            effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
            actions: ['S3:*'],
            resources: ['*'],
          }),
        ],
      })
    );
```

With that role, I can create, read and delete files with no issues from the API. When the API tries to create a pre-signed post however, I get the error:

```
Error: Unable to create a POST object policy without a bucket, region, and credentials
```

It seems super strange to me that I can run the other operations, but it fails with the presignedPOST, especially since my S3 actions are all allowed.

```
    const post: aws.S3.PresignedPost = await s3.createPresignedPost({
      Bucket: bucket,
      Fields: { key },
      Expires: 60,
      Conditions: [['content-length-range', 0, 5242880]],
    });
```

Here is the code I use. I am logging the bucket and key so I'm positive that they are valid values. One thought I had was when running locally, I will run aws.configure to set my keys but in Fargate I purposefully omit that. I thought that it was getting the right keys since the other s3 operations work without fail. Am I approaching this right?

Answer (score 0):

When using IAM role credentials with AWS sdk, you must either use the asynchronous (callback) version of `createPresignedPost` or guarantee that your credentials have been resolved before calling the `await` version of this method.

Something like this will work with IAM based credentials:

```js
const s3 = new AWS.S3()

const _presign = params => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    s3.createPresignedPost(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) return rej(err)
      return res(data)
    })
  })
}

// await _presign(...)  <- works
// await s3.createPresignedPost(...)  <- won't work
```

Refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createPresignedPost-property